# Highcharts skip columns when plotting

Tags: highcharts

how would you go about skipping columns when plotting.  Specifically, I have data that looks like:

```
week,area1,area2,area3,area4,area5,area6,area7
1,5,5,5,5,5,5,5
2,6,6,6,6,6,6,6
3,7,7,7,7,7,7,7
```

I'm doing 2 multi-line charts.  The first graphs area1, area2 & area3 and the second one graphs area4,5,6.  In the first chart, I can easily keep the "week" as my X values and only do the first three areas by:

```
data: {
    csv: csv,
    startColumn: 0,
    endColumn: 3
},
```

But obviously when I do the second chart, if I do

```
data: {
    csv: csv,
    startColumn: 4,
    endColumn: 8
},
```

I get one of the area values as my X axis.  I can understand that, but was wondering if you can easily skip the middle columns and only graph column(0) (my "week") and then columns 5 - 8?

I have seen nothing that would be like:

```
startColumn: 0,
excludeColumns: 1-4,
endColumn: 8
```

or something similar.  Do you think that's available or would I have to split the input into arrays and weed it out there?

Comment: I thinkinthis case you can use `parsed` callback for data manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get columns 0 and 5-8, use this:

```
data: {
    csv: csv,
    startColumn: 0,
    endColumn: 8,
    parsed: function (columns) {
        $.each(columns, function () {
            this.splice(1, 4);
        });
    }
},
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks yuk.  I would not have thought about at all.  Cheers!